# Why and when are linking verbs omitted?

Tags: headline-english, military, whiz-deletion, linking-verbs, gaming

I see that linking verbs are omitted when one wants to quickly convey information (radio communication, newspapers).

Examples: enemy spotted, game over, Lincoln shot, block broken, 3 left.

1. Are there any other cases when linking verbs are omitted (firefighters without radio?)?
2. Do the military omit linking verbs during communication without a radio when they're at war?
3. Why do video games omit linking verbs? For the same reason as newspapers do (headlines style)?

I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I say "Coming!" for "I am coming!", and why?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160482/can-i-say-coming-for-i-am-coming-and-why) See also [Why is the subject omitted in sentences like 'Thought you'd never ask'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66972/why-is-the-subject-omitted-in-sentences-like-thought-youd-never-ask/66994#66994)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth this does not!

Comment: John Lawler includes (about subject + auxiliary omission( 'Let me reiterate that this phenomenon only occurs in speaking English, and in other informal communication systems like email and txting that work like speech. It is not good formal written style, except for reporting dialog in a story.'  ELU deals with standard English, so the jargon of firefighters, the military, electronic gaming are more properly asked on dedicated sites. Doubtless they do for conciseness, and doubtless they take care not to leave ambiguous fragments in the services.